# WAV duration in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

Hi I need to calculate Wav duration in PHP using this code but have this error .

```html
  $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
  if (fread($fp,4) == "RIFF") {
    fseek($fp, 20);
    $rawheader = fread($fp, 16);
    $header = unpack('vtype/vchannels/Vsamplerate/Vbytespersec/valignment/vbits',$rawheader);
    $pos = ftell($fp);
    while (fread($fp,4) != "data" && !feof($fp)) {
      $pos++;
      fseek($fp,$pos);
    }
    $rawheader = fread($fp, 4);
    $data = unpack('Vdatasize',$rawheader);
    $sec = $data[datasize]/$header[bytespersec];
    $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
    $seconds = intval($sec % 60);
    return str_pad($minutes,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT).":".str_pad($seconds,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  }
```

Warning (2): unpack(): Type V: not enough input, need 4, have 0 
Warning (2): unpack() [function.unpack]: Type V: not enough input, need 4, have 0